# Bootstrap navbar links doesnt work on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Anyone could help me with navbar links in Bootstrap3?

http://www.mebleroberto.co.uk/fabrics

Why links are working fine on desktop view, but not in a mobile view (nothing happened on click)?

Comment: Check my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected your click events it seems it doesn't retrieve the `nav-section` and also the `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` stops the click event.

[image]

Besides the homepage has links like `<a href="#" data-nav-section="meble">FURNITURE</a>` and also section that scroll through

[image]

My conclusion is that your mobile menu should not conflict the home menu by changing either the id `#gtco-offcanvas` or disabling this part of code on the other pages.

Replacing the class `linki_menu_b` with external on the menu of other pages except the homepage seemed to work. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - problem was "external linki_menu_b" class on links. According to

```
$('body').on('click', '#gtco-offcanvas ul a:not([class="external"]), 
.main-nav a:not([class="external"])
```

my links previously had "class='external linki_menu_b'" - i removed class 'lin ki_menu_b' and everything works fine now.